# What is the time complexity of tree traversal using yield from?

Tags: python, time-complexity, yield

An example of depth-first tree traversal:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
        self._children = []

    def add_child(self, child):
        self._children.append(child)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._children)

    def depth_first(self):
        yield self
        for c in self:
            yield from c.depth_first()
```

I understand that `yield from` does not consume the generator right away, but instead pass the `yield` upward to its caller.

But this process of **passing** still exists, and thus `yield` will be passed from every node all the way up to its root, and we can describe the running time by the recurrence (assume it is a binary tree for simplicity, but the idea is the same):

> T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + Θ(n)

`Θ(n)` exists because this node has to pass all the `yield` passed from its offsprings to its parent. And the time complexity derived from the formula above is:

> O(nlogn)

However, the time complexity of tree traversal is only `O(n)` if I do not use `yield` or `yield from` at all.

I am wondering whether I misunderstand how `yield` works or it is simply not feasible to write a recursive generator like this.

Comment: Shouldn't Θ(n) in your formula be Θ(1)? Isn't number of offspring of a node in a balanced tree constant?

Comment: @DYZ I think it should be Θ(n). It does not pass the number of offsprings, but passes the `yield` statement from all of its offsprings.

Comment: Does 'all of its offspring' include the offspring of offspring, etc.? (I assume that it does not.) If not, it is still a constant.

Comment: @DYZ It does include the offsprings of offsprings, since each node will do two things: (1) yield itself to its caller (2) yield its offsprings and the offsprings of its offsprings that its offsprings yield to it and etc...

Comment: Oh, you are right. Then it is indeed O(n log n), because you essentially delegate the traversal results to the root node, instead of using them locally.

Answer (score 2):

From the official Python 3.3 release for `yield from`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/

> Using a specialised syntax opens up possibilities for optimisation
>   when there is a long chain of generators. Such chains can arise, for
>   instance, when recursively traversing a tree structure. The overhead
>   of passing **next**() calls and yielded values down and up the chain
>   can cause what ought to be an O(n) operation to become, in the worst
>   case, O(n**2).
>
> A possible strategy is to add a slot to generator
>   objects to hold a generator being delegated to. When a **next**() or
>   send() call is made on the generator, this slot is checked first, and
>   if it is nonempty, the generator that it references is resumed
>   instead. If it raises StopIteration, the slot is cleared and the main
>   generator is resumed.
>
> This would reduce the delegation overhead to a
>   chain of C function calls involving no Python code execution. A
>   possible enhancement would be to traverse the whole chain of
>   generators in a loop and directly resume the one at the end, although
>   the handling of StopIteration is more complicated then.

It looks like `yield from` still requires traversing up the tree. But that traversing is done by the interpreter in C instead of in Python. So technically it's still a O(n) overhead, but it's not as bad as it sounds.

Comment: Is it a resolved issue, or are they still working on it?